# Using RasterLite in a Cordova App

Tags: web-mapping, spatialite, offline, cordova, rasterlite

I would like to use RasterLite data in a [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)-based App but don't know the right tools to achieve this.

The [Geopaparazzi Project] uses [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/) files generated with the [rasterlite2](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/librasterlite2/wiki?name=basic_concepts) library to display a background map.

From what I understand this raster data storage technology is less performant
in comparison to [MBTiles](https://www.mapbox.com/help/an-open-platform/) since they do not contain prerendered tiles for every zoom level (in a mapping library like OpenLayers) but instead use (physical or virtual) pyramids to render data for smaller zoom level which makes it storage efficient. Bigger mosaics can be tiled for smaller zoomlevels and still be utilized in a mobile app.

The Geopaparazzi app mentioned above is Android-based. I would now like to use RasterLite data a in webbased, mobile (hybrid) app to display a basemap for a larger area. While plugins for OpenLayers or [Leaflet exist for MBTiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles), there seems to be no plugin for RasterLite.

How can this be done sing existing components like Chris Brody's [cordova-sqlite-ext](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext) or the [JavaScript port of SpatiaLite](https://github.com/jvail/spatiasql.js/tree/master)?

Comment: Rasterlite is a deprecated project, use rasterlite2 instead.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear: I meant rasterlite2. I edited the question. My question remains.